# setting NSMutableParagraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple causes the UILabel to clip it's top

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a UILabel in a UITableViewCell. When I set the attributed string on the UILabel, which adjusts the `lineHeightMultiple`, it clips the top of the text in the label.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.75

var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: value)
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

// showLabel.clipsToBounds = false // has no effect
showLabel.attributedText = attrString
// showLabel.sizeToFit() // also appears to have no effect
```

It's like the top of the text is pull up bast the bounds of the UILabel.
Has anyone encountered this? If so, any recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845705/uitextview-lineheightmultiple-clips-top-first-line-of-text

Comment: Have you tried to set `maxLineHeight` and `minLineHeight` to the same number ? For example , set both of them to `23`. More than ,set the `lineHeightMultiple ` to `1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get bounds of attributed string and set frame or constraints for label after set text for it

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options 
               context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Comment: Ya I tried that. It's a no go.  I even artificially set the height constraint to a value well above what the 2 lines would be. Regardless, when I set `lineHeightMultiple` it pulls the top line up and clips.