# UITextView lineHeightMultiple Clips Top, first line, of Text

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In iOS 8, I have a vanilla `UITextView` that clips the top of the 1st line when a `lineHeightMultiple` is applied to it's `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, see image below:

[image: Text Clipping]

It appears as though `lineHeightMultiple` affects the 1st line of text in addition to subsequent lines.

Setting `clipsToBounds = false` on the `UITextView` will at least enable the clipped part to show, but you can see from the image below that now the top part of the text is obviously above it's frame:

[image: Text Above Frame]

I can fix this by just setting the top constraint on the offending `UITextView` to compensate for `clipsToBounds = false` but that feels like a hack to me.

I have also tried using a `WKWebView` for the offending text, and just setting the css `line-height` property, and that works just fine. There must simply be something I am missing when it comes to UITextView though.

Additionally, setting `lineSpacing` on the paragraph style to less than 0 has no affect, per the docs:

```
The distance in points between the bottom of one line fragment 
and the top of the next.

**This value is always nonnegative.**

This value is included in the line fragment heights in the 
layout manager.
```

I have also tried setting the `contentInset` of the `UITextView` as well as using a system font, both had not affect.

My sample code for this setup follows:

```
let text = "THIS IS A MULTILINE RUN OF TEXT"

let font = UIFont(name: "MyFontName", size: 31.0)!
// let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(31.0)

let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.lineHeightMultiple = 0.75
paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

let attributes = [
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph,
              NSFontAttributeName: font
]

titleView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)

// titleView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
titleView.clipsToBounds = false
```

Has anyone encountered this and overcome or is the top constraint hack the only way to go?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

I compensated it using NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName.

You should use:

```
let attributes = [
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph,
    NSFontAttributeName: font,
    NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: -5
]
```

You will have to also set a lower paragraph.lineHeightMultiple.

A little tricky, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Cooliopas is right, but I ended up using this in a label extension and needed something more suited for the many different sizes of text throughout my app. I found that the baseline adjustment to keep the text vertically centered was 10% of the height of the text.

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: newText)

let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = self.textAlignment
style.lineSpacing = 1.0
style.lineHeightMultiple = 0.75

var baselineOffset : CGFloat = -5 //-5 is a default for this in case there is no attributedText size to reference
if let size = self.attributedText?.size(){
  baselineOffset = size.height * -0.1
} else {
  NSLog("attributedText = nil, setting lineHeightMultiple to -5 as a default for ", newText)
}

attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
attrString.addAttribute(NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, value: baselineOffset, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
self.clipsToBounds = false

self.attributedText = attrString
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach - use a stack view with two labels, and set the stack view spacing to the top label's font's descender.